# I cannot locate two child classes if matching the parent class and URL using XPath Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to locate the element for one parent that match the following requirements:

Here is the link below:
https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword=mattress

#### Parent Class

```html
<div class ="col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item" data-sqe="item">
```

#### Child class

```html
<a data-sqe="link" href= "all urls that is printed in python.">
```

#### Child class contains this element

```html
<div class = "_1gkBDw _2O43P5">
<div class = "_1HvBLA">
<div class = "_3ao649" data-sqe="ad"> Ad</div>
```

Just inspect the element of the top bar:

[image]

Which has the highlighted "Ad" shown.

Here is what am I trying to achieve:
The user clicks on the specific product page that contains the ads bar of the product page.

Here is my code:

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
"//div[@class='col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item' and @data-
sqe='item'][.//a[@data-sqe='link' and @href='" + result[i] +"']]"))).click()
```

The XPath expression supposes to locate the parent:

`//div[@class="col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item"]` and one `href "/Direct-Export-Super-Single-Mattress-Synthetic-Latex-(6-Inches)-i.281593956.6140904430"` which works perfectly and clicks it.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
"//div[@class='col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item' and @data-
sqe='item'][@class='_1HvBLA'][@class = '_3ao649' and @data-sqe =
'ad'][.//a[@data-sqe='link' and @href='" + all_urls[i] +"']]")))
```

It doesn't work when I try to locate two more elements parent `//div[@class="_1HvBLA"]` and child `//div[@class="_3ao649"]` together click it, because it doesn't appear to click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t have to use classes. You can use CSS selector, like

```
div[data-sqe=item] a[data-sqe=link]
```

This should work (try it in Chrome browser element search in Developer Tools).

I would recommend you to pass the [CSS Diner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FL2oZ4xBAU) online game to learn to use CSS selectors.

Comment: @RPWheler 

the first code works fine thou, however, the last three class is the one its a bit sketchy 
```WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item' and @data-sqe='item'][@class='_1HvBLA'][@class = '_3ao649' and @data-sqe = 'ad'][.//a[@data-sqe='link' and @href='" + all_urls[i] +"']]")))``` here is the code

Comment: It is always best two places those 2 classes in check so that I can detect any changes.

Comment: CSS diner has some issues